# error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

When I use GooglePluse Library file it works on iphone simulator.

But when I run it on device it gives  the following Error:

```
 ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_GooglePlusSignIn in /Pratik workspace/Fitness 
     app/Fitness Ap/Fitness/lib/libGooglePlusUniversal.a(GooglePlusSignIn.o) and /Pratik 
     workspace/Fitness app/Fitness Ap/Fitness/lib/libGooglePlus.a(GooglePlusSignIn.o) for 
     architecture armv7 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to 
     see invocation)
```

Comment: Check linker flags -ObjC and -fobjc-arc is added in terget info

Answer (score -1):

you will have 2 files with same name that's why it is giving error like this.

go in targets ->Build Phases ->Compile sources and try to remove GooglePlusSignIn file.it will be there i think.
then run again and let me know whether it is working or not..!!!

Happy coding...!!!!

Comment: hey nirav
i check all files there is no duplicate files

Comment: have you tried to remove GooglePlusSignIn file from Build Phase?

Comment: GooglePlusSignIn is only .h (header file)

Comment: don't you have any GooglePlusSignIn.m file in Compile sources? ok check that whether compile sources contain libGooglePlusUniversal.m and libGooglePlus.m file?

Comment: i have libGooglePlus.a and libGooglePlusUniversal.a files